# Button to toggle on selecting a specific option from dropdown using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu

M stuck in Angular Js. I want to toggle the button between left and middle when I select a specific option from the dropdown.

By default the button is at middle. I want to toggle it to left only when I select "one" from the dropdown and remain at middle for the rest of the options.

This is the half baked code I have written
  (Index.html)

```
<div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">

<h4>Radio &amp; Uncheckable Radio</h4>
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>

</div>
```

The Js file is as follows:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ButtonsCtrl', function($scope){  $scope.radioModel = 'Middle';$scope.items = ['one','two','three','four'];});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you create fiddle or plunker link replicating this issue??

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/dXa4XRLThZyTIUt64mDe?p=preview @SameerK

Comment: Are you sure the link is right one? as i don't see any related code there.

Comment: Yup. I can open the link from here

Comment: In your controller you can use ``$watch`` to get selected option value to add login for specific option.   To give you the complete solution would like to know whether you want move both buttons to toggle left on selection of option one or do you want hide one button and show other button ??

Comment: I want both the buttons to be enabled and move only one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve that, I would suggest adding an `ng-change` function to the `<select>` element, like so :

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"  ng-change="changeFunction()">
```

What this function does, is to check if the current selected item is equal to "one" and if so, set the `$scope.radioModdel` to "Left". In all other cases, set it to "Middle". The code is below:

```
$scope.changeFunction = function(){
  if(this.selectedItem == 'one')
    $scope.radioModel = 'Left';
  else
    $scope.radioModel = 'Middle';
}
```

Here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Agczy5?p=preview).

You could read more about the way angular handles select elements on their [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: @IshitaMengi Glad I could help! If you believe I answered your question, don't forget to select my answer as correct :)